# Push notifications - Expo

Tags: react-native, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, expo, apple-push-notifications

I have an android app built using Expo.
My iOS app however is built using swift.

From my iOS app when I send a message, My android (expo) app receives a push notification.
But when I send a message from android, my iOS device doesn't receive push notifications.
iOS to iOS also works fine.

My push notifications are working using fcm and APNs.

Im following these instructions
https://docs.expo.io/push-notifications/sending-notifications-custom/#fcm-server

Im getting stuck on the following:

```
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
```

and

```
const http2 = require('http2');
```

Which npm packages do I need to install to use `jsonwebtoken` and `http2`.